# How do I determine the width of a CCLabelBMFont once I've created it?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

After creating a label and adding to a layer, I need to find out how wide the text is on the screen.

```
[node textureRect].size.width
```

...is what I would normally use with sprites, so how would I find out with CCLabelBMFont?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `label.texture.contentSize.width` or `label.contentSize.width`.

Comment: Note that label.texture.contentSize gives you the size of the texture, whereas label.contentSize gives you only the part of the texture that is "used" by the label image. This distinction is important for 1st & 2nd generation devices which required texture dimensions to be power of 2 dimensions. That means the texture width could be 256 but the actual contentSize width might be only 200 points!